# Main user can't edit or run script, cronfile in SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, nginx, cron

I have a VPS with Intel XeonCPU E3-1270 V2 @ 3.50GHz running on OpenVZ Webuzo + nginx

I used to edit cronjobs or other files as the main user via SSH. But it seems that I've lost all the privilege after restarting MySQL to fix a sudden CPU usage spike.

I get these errors when opening, accessing or saving files:

```
"user is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.”

[user@vm root]$ php info.php
Could not open input file: info.php
[user@vm root]$ vi hello.text
E212: Can't open file for writing"
```

And when I run `crontab -e` and `crontab -l`, they return nothing. They just show:

```
[user@vm root]$ crontab -e
[user@vm root]$
```

Not sure if it has anything to do with me restarting the server, httpd, and MySQL. What should I do to get back the privilege back to the main user?

Answer (score 0):

```
[user@vm root]$ php info.php
Could not open input file: info.php
[user@vm root]$ vi hello.text
E212: Can't open file for writing"
```

> > It seems you are logged in as the "user" and your current location is /root.
> >     You are allowed to write contents to /home/user and not /root if you are logged in as the "user".

And when I run crontab -e and crontab -l, they return nothing.

> > Possibly your CRON service is not responding for some reason.
> >     Re-installing the service will be a quick fix.

What should I do to get back the privilege back to the main user?

> > su - 
> >     and fill in your root users' password to get you privileges.

Good Luck